# Запрос к mysql используя api Drupal7

Tags: mysql, drupal

Как записать запрос

```
SELECT t2.* , (SELECT group_concat(ID) FROM Table1) as t1 FROM Table2 as t2 WHERE t2.ID = 1;
```

используя `api drupal7`.